# How does Catholic Church explain John 1:31?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospel-of-john, john-the-baptist

At John 1:30-31  (NRSVCE) we see John the Baptist introducing Jesus to the crowd:

> "This is he of whom I said, ‘After me comes a man who ranks ahead of me because he was before me.’  I myself did not know him; but I came baptizing with water for this reason, that he might be revealed to Israel."

John's mother Elizabeth was a relative of Mary, mother of Jesus (Lk 1:36) . As such, both John and Jesus would have known each other from childhood. Apparently, John's saying "I myself did not know him.."has a deeper meaning. My question therefore, is: How does the Catholic Church explain the statement of John the Baptist that he did not know Jesus ?

Comment: Totally un-useful comment in the footnotes of the NAB `I did not know him: this gospel shows no knowledge of the tradition (Luke 1) about the kinship of Jesus and John the Baptist.`  http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0839/_PX9.HTM#$3QL

Comment: A [related](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/31842) question. Knowing Jesus personally, and being aware that he is the Christ, are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Commenting on John 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/John1.htm):31, St. Thomas Aquinas explains "*the statement of John the Baptist that he did not know Jesus*" by saying that he

> 263. […] precludes an erroneous conjecture from his testimony. For someone might say that John bore witness to Christ because of his affection for him, coming from a special friendship. And so, excluding this, John says, *And I did not know him!;* for **John had lived in the desert from boyhood**. And although **many miracles** happened during the birth of Christ, such as the Magi and the star and so on, they **were not known to John**: both because **he was an infant at the time**, and because, **after withdrawing to the desert, he had no association with Christ**. In the interim **between his birth and baptism, Christ did not perform any miracles**, but led a life similar to any other person, and **his power remained unknown to all**.